# MVC5/EF/LINQ - Multiple Select Count queries returned to a view, best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am creating my first MVC5 / EF / LINQ application and I would like to display the results of several (about 75) "Select Count(*)" queries in one view. The purpose is to display different statistics from a single table on a home page "dashboard", along with a list of "active" items from the same table in the database.

I have read different opinions on how the best way run select county queries
in LINQ... What is the most efficient way to do this considering how many queries I need to run on the page?

A sample query would be

```
select count(*) from TableName WHERE LType="A" AND (LDate BETWEEN 02/10/2015 AND 02/25/2015)

public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.LastNameSortParam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "LastName" : "";
        ViewBag.DateSortParam = sortOrder == "Date" ? "LeadDate" : "Date";
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var newLeads = from l in db.WebLeads
                       where (l.LoanAgent == null || l.LoanAgent == "hb@mwfinc.com")
                       select l;                           
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            newLeads = newLeads.Where(l => l.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                   || l.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Date":
                newLeads = newLeads.OrderBy(l => l.LeadDate);
                break;
            case "LeadDate":
                newLeads = newLeads.OrderByDescending(l => l.LeadDate);
                break;
            case "LastName":
                newLeads = newLeads.OrderBy(l => l.LastName);
                break;
            default:
                newLeads = newLeads.OrderByDescending(l => l.LeadDate);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 15;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        DateTime minDate = System.DateTime.Today;
        DateTime maxDate = System.DateTime.Now;

        // Leads to Be Assigned Daily Count
        var ctPurchTBA = db.WebLeads.Count(x => (x.LoanType == "Home Purchase" || x.LoanType == "CalPATH Home Purchase")
                              && x.LeadDate >= minDate
                              && x.LeadDate <= maxDate);


        return View(newLeads.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));                        
    }
```

'

Comment: Depending on load/size of tables/overall performance considerations I would go with two approaches:

1. Have one select with sub-selects with the select count(*) as sub-selects. You would need to pass only one item to the vew
2. Load the totals with asyncronous requests from the frontend based with different schedules on table load/volume to reduce sql load.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of approach 1?  I am a bit of a newbie, unfortunately, so your answer went a bit over my head.

Comment: Since you are using EF/Linq, why dont you use your POCO instead of pure sql.
Something like var myPoco = YourDBContext.models
And then you can work with mypoco and query it as you prefer

Comment: example: `select tab1.numbers1, tab2.numbers2, tab3.numbers3 from 
(select count(*) as numbers1 from Table1) as tab1,
(select count(*) as numbers2 from Table2) as tab2,
(select count(*) as numbers3 from Table3) as tab3` but be aware that this is a **performance overfill** for an SQL server to handle especially if you talk about 75 tables. Personally I would go with an async process but this is my personal view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Osadella in the comments, you can use the POCO generated by Entity Framework to do this in a much more sane way.

You can do this in SQL, as you're already aware. The problem with using `count` in SQL is that it is not very performant. You're not gonna notice any huge difference with a dataset like the one you've mentioned, but it's worth knowing that large enterprise applications suffer when using SQL `count`.

To answer your question however, you should probably use LINQ on the POCO (big data model generated by your `DbContext` in EF) for the simple reason that you can use it. LINQ is a much simpler abstraction over SQL, there are some fairly good examples [here](http://www.linqpad.net/whylinqbeatssql.aspx) about the benefits of LINQ.

You can use SQL based LINQ or you can use method based LINQ, I'd use method based because it's a lot more readable and easier to write.

The code above;

```
select count(*) 
from TableName 
WHERE LType="A" 
AND (LDate BETWEEN 02/10/2015 AND 02/25/2015)
```

would become:

```
var count = db.TableNames.Count(x => x.LType == "A" 
                                  && x.LDate >= minDate 
                                  && x.LDate <= maxDate);
```

Obviously you'd need to define `minDate` and `maxDate` somewhere as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.  This may be out of the scope of the question, but how do I return the results of that query to my view?  I have the query set up in my controller.  The controller also returns a paginated list of records from the same table that I am querying for the count.    See below.  Am I setting this up correctly, should the count queries be in the controller?  I added the code in the controller to my original post...  If I could get an example of how to pass this to the view, I think everything would fall into place for me.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: How much do you know about View models?

Comment: I am new to MVC from Web Forms.  This is my first application.  I have 2 books, but I keep getting hung up on passing multiple models to the view.  I have created a database first model for my existing database.   Everything thing that I want to do in my above example is from 1 table, so wouldn't I be using just 1 model?

Comment: You would be using 1 model yeah, but you'd be using a View model which contains both your domain models.

Comment: [Check out this MVC5 Fundamentals tutorial by Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m1-introduction&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals)

Comment: Two of my recent answers regarding the use of View models: [first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28701771/3846058) and [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696183/how-to-set-and-get-id-of-buttons-created-within-a-loop/28696785#28696785)

Comment: If you need any more help, [you can join me in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71720/discussion-between-sippy-and-daniela).