# ViewBag is not written in output for Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

`ViewBag` value is completely ignored while running ASP.NET MVC4 web page.

[image]

Here is the source for above image.
Even though I am checking if the `ViewBag.SearchResultsJson` is null or empty, ViewBag still isn't written in the output.

```
<script>
    @{
        HtmlString jsonText = new HtmlString("");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.SearchResultsJson))
        {
            jsonText = Html.Raw(ViewBag.SearchResultsJson);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var json = @jsonText;
        app.value('searchResultsJson', json);
    })
</script>
```

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: Post the actual code. Not a picture of the code.

Comment: [Don't use ViewBag, use a Viewmodel instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696183/how-to-set-and-get-id-of-buttons-created-within-a-loop/28696785#28696785)

Comment: @sippy Thanks for posting actual code from my screenshot.

Comment: @sippy I am using a ViewModel for getting/setting form data already. Maybe my design for the page is not optimal for this being my first MVC project.

Comment: Always use a viewmodel property over ViewBag. ViewBag is never necessary and is harder to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your code, an empty `jsonText` is a valid scenario so I won't focus on why this variable is empty.

The reason for your error is you're not wrapping `@jsonText` with quotes to render a valid string on Javascript side.

You should change

```
var json = @jsonText;
```

by

```
var json = '@jsonText';
```