# i need to pass the values of multiple checkbox items to the controller from the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@model IEnumerable<State>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>State Data</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateState")
</p>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>
            Search by Name: @Html.TextBox("searchstring") <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
        </p>
    }
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Station)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Station)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Update State Data", "UpdateStation", new {id = item.Id}) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteState", new {id = item.Id})  | Select to Include in Charts

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

This is my code, i need to input a `@Html.Checkbox()` for every item, then pass the values of the selected items to the controller and create a chart with those values..

I know how to make the chart, i just don't know how to use the checkbox and pass the values.

```
{
    [Table("State")]
    public class State
    {
        public State()
        {
            Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Station { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What data should be in checkbox? Show your model please

Comment: i want to be able to pass the name and station of each selected item, so i can use them to create a chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add a bool field like @Sippy suggests make sure you change your @foreach to a @for loop so you can get the full collection back from the view to your controller

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].Selected) @* new bool field *@
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Station)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].Station)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Update State Data", "UpdateStation", new { id = Model[i].Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteState", new { id = Model[i].Id })  | Select to Include in Charts

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Then your action can accept a List and you can use linq to get the selected items

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<State> model)
{
    var selected = model.Where(a => a.Selected == true);
```

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hFbtmp)

Comment: Why would you need to do that? O_o if he implements what I said, the only change will be the target collection for the foreach will need to become `@Model.States`

Comment: he wants to `be able to pass the name and station of each selected item, so i can use them to create a chart`  simply adding a checkbox would not accomplish this

Comment: That's why I inherited the domain model, so he can still access those attributes.

Comment: but how are you passing the values back to the controller?.. by having all the fields names the same?..thats what `@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected)`  would do and won't work

Comment: i added a DotNetFiddle example of how it would work.  feel free to add your own using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected)` and show us how that would work

Comment: Ah yeah, weird. He still shouldn't be modifying the domain model for this.

Comment: I suppose you could add your own indexing to each checkbox but at that point you'd be overcomplicated, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

[Adapted user5103147's DNF to incorporate the Viewmodel idea :)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V2WkTE)

Do try to use mapping instead of inheritance though.

---

In your `State` model, add a `bool` variable. The default editor for `bool` variables is a checkbox, if you add it to the `State` model then the DefaultModelBinder should pick it up.

As for passing to the controller, perhaps you should consider using a viewmodel.

Your implementation of that would look a little like this:

```
public class StateListViewModel 
{
    public List<StateViewModel> States { get; set; }
}


public class StateViewModel : State
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can access those values. I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701494/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key/28701771#28701771) which links to something Darin Dimitrov wrote about View models, worth the read.

If you implement the above, you can provide a checkbox for each item and place the table in a form, which can then be submitted to the controller using the View model. This will give you a 'selected' value for each item, and you can use that to build your chart.

Also should be noted that it's often not always a fantastic idea to inherit a domain model with your view model, but it's not gonna kill you. The better option would be to create a mapper to map between the two, or use Automapper.